# how to access Jupyter notebook list item

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlZe.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlvbN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m3DS.png)
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also
How to solve this error there is no content on YouTube also

Comment: The first error you posted, where you used brackets, gave good feedback on how to address it. Don't use a string. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and next time adhere to its suggestions as a guide. In particular pay close attention to the section entitled 'Help others reproduce your problem' where it emphasizes **not to share errors as screenshots** and to share the code and full error as text in the post. Please look at other good examples of posts to further guide you.

Comment: Please, also note that the problem is Python and not due to Jupyter. If you ran you code in a Python console/interpreter or as a traditional Python script on the command line, I suspect you'd have the same issue. And so know where the issue lies will help you search better for answers in the future. Plus, you don't want to emphasize Jupyter in the title and the category tag when running the Python code elsewhere will give the same result. You can mention you happen to be using Jupyter to run Python in the main post in case you are missing something special you are unaware of though.